# My Huawei u8160 is restarting automatically

Tags: cyanogenmod, overclocking

I have a Huawei u8160 running Cyanogenmod 7.2 that always restarts automatically.

My phone is clocked to 122-600 while my phone's CPU's Max frequency 558.

I'm using the SMARTASSV2 governor and it mostly restarts when it is sleeping.

So I want to know what restarts my phone automatically?

Comment: Why would it meltdown ? Maybe because the excessive frequency ?

Comment: most probably it crashed and the watchdog circuit triggered a restart. Aka: yor Mod is still unstable.

Comment: @ce4 what crashed? and what is the watchdog circuit?

Comment: I've heard that the smartassv2 governor caps the frequency to the lowest while sleeping,maybe my lower frequency is not right?

Comment: @MohamedEssam Check my answer, it might shed some light at your current problem.

Comment: @Mohamed: Here's a wikpedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer) about watchdogs in computing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summarized Answer:

The main issue your facing is that you're using SmartassV2/ondemandX that was developed for stock kernels. But you're using it with a non stock kernel, the CyanogenMod 7.2. See bellow a summary for each of them.

Useful reading: [A Beginner’s Guide to Android Kernels](http://www.vikitech.com/8239/beginners-guide-android-kernels)

---

### SmartassV2/ondemandX governors

Stock kernel is the factory firmware. If you're using SmartassV2/ondemandX governors, they are modules for phones with stock kernels because they don't have 'smartass' or ondemandX' governors:

- XDA Developers Forum :: [SmartassV2/ondemandX governors for Rooted/stock ROM | 2012-02-24](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1514359)

  Last updated: by AnDyX; 16th May 2012 at 07:47 AM.

> This modules are for people with stock kernels because they don't have 'smartass' or ondemandX' governors.
>
> Differences between this modules and build in stock kernels:
>
> - allows to set max CPU freq when screen is off (to save battery),
> - allows to set starting CPU freq when phone awakes (to speed up awake process),
> - allows set/change almost all aspects of governor (to suite needs),
> - should be a bit more responsive when parameters are well chosen for smartassv2 governor.

---

### CyanogenMod 7.2.0-RC1

The current CyanogenMod 7.2.0-RC1 U8160 Port status is stable, but there are some known issues reported.

**Already fixed reboot related issues:**

1. v0.9 (20120203):

   - Hotfix 4test5 [21 Feb]: Revert longterm patches due to random reboot issue.
2. v0.7 - 22 January 2012:

   - Kernel stability fix (disabled SCHED_HRTICK due to instability/random reboot issue).

**Note:** *Check your version. The latest is v1.3 released at 2012-06-25.*

---

Use the link bellow to get detailed information about the development and what users are reporting. If you've got a version above v0.9, consider [reporting your issue](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17496484&postcount=2), thus allowing the developer to deal with it. If your version isn't the latest, consider changing to it.

- XDA Developers Forum :: [Huawei U8160/U8180 CyanogenMod 7.2.0-RC1 U8160 Port](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1259739)

  Latest release: v1.3
  Last updated: by psyke83; 25th June 2012 at 01:57 PM.
  Thread responses: 3830

Comment: the last version is 2/7/2012 not 25/6/2012 and i have installed it already and then it started random rebooting

Comment: @MohamedEssam Can you provide a link for the version released on 02-07-2012? Didn't saw any mention to it...

Comment: i downloaded it from goomanager.

Comment: @MohamedEssam The release from 02-07-2012 isn't an official one yet. There's still some bugs being fixed. That's the reason as to why she doesn't appear on the changelog.

Comment: but the 25/6/2012 one has too many bugs the most obvious one is that all the sensors aren't working well.that what made me install that one.

Comment: @MohamedEssam You need to wait for a more stable version! Nonetheless, my summary at the top of my answer continues to be the answer to your issue, you're overclocking your hardware with software for factory ROMs, not custom ROMs like the one you're using.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4213/discussion-between-zuul-and-mohamed-essam)